# Is it cheat to use spline to interpolate data from experiment or computational results.

Tags: computer-science, spline

Say we got data from the experiment or computational results.

However, instead of using the line to connect data one by one. We use the spline to interpolate the data to make it look more smooth.

Also, we can use the different curve to interpolate. What curve should we believe? [image]

Comment: i don't quite get the dark gray curve called *"Original"*.  isn't the original data points **only** those little circles?  it appears that this data you generated is from a quadratic function (all points except one like on that quadratic) with one point deliberately offset.  why does the *"Original"* curve not go through that offset point?

Comment: looks like your *original* data is: $$ y_n = n^2 + 19 \delta_{n-1} \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z}, -5 \le n \le 5$$ and where $$\delta_m \triangleq \begin{cases} 1 \qquad & m = 0 \\  0 \qquad & m \ne 0 \\ \end{cases} $$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).  is that correct?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You are right. Also, the data is not from my experiment but just for making my meaning clear. In the figure, you can see, there are many different splines that can interpolate the point. However, is it ok to do that for the experiment data. Thank you very much.

Comment: okay, but that *"Original"* curve that goes through $(1,1)$ instead of $(1,20)$ is **not** an interpolated curve nor anything that is derived from the data that includes your point at $(1,20)$, correct?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Correct, To be more accurately, it omit the point at (1,20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "cheat", but it certainly is misleading. You're giving a false impression of how much certainty you have. If you had splines for which the number of points in each spline were significantly greater than the order of the spline, that would be a different matter, but otherwise splines are pretty much the definition of overfitting. The curve is doing something different in the interval [0,2], and three points isn't nearly enough to say what that something different is, so drawing a smooth curve as if you can say anything with any degree of certainty as to what's going on in the intervals (0,1) and (1,2) is highly misleading. The data point at x=1 seems to be a clear outlier, and you should look into what could be causing it. As it is, simply presenting a scatterplot would be the most honest presentation.

Comment: I got it, Thank you for letting me know about *overfitting*. This is the new word for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, overfitting will make the curve have abnormal oscillation as the figure shows, right?

Comment: @ytyyutianyunYes, choosing a polynomial with degree equal to, or close to, the number of points, will cause the curve to vary wildly depending on the points chosen. Splines decrease this effect somewhat, as the really dramatic overfitting happens outside the interval. For instance, you can look at the polynomial from just the points x = 0,1,2 and see what it does outside the interval. It will quickly go way outside where the actual points are.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much. ❀